# Weird Pycharm terminal prompt after using coloredlog library

Tags: python, pycharm

```
xyz-M2: nshk$ python
>>> import coloredlog, logger
>>> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
>>>coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')
>>>coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG', logger=logger)
>>>logger.warning("this is a warning message")
```

After exit() from python shell my prompt got changed (looks exactly like below)and I`m unable to fix it.

```
133;C;1337;RemoteHost=nshk@NSHK-M21337;CurrentDir=/Users/nshk/PycharmProjects/tool133;D;0133;A(env1) NSHK-M2:tool nshk$ 133;B
```

I tried to uninstall coloredlog library, still no use.

Comment: after you uninstall have you restarted pycharm?